# Расстояние между точками на плоскости

Tags: алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть у меня плоскость 255x255 разбитая на квадратные сектора одинакового размера и нужно найти  найти расстояние между двумя точками. Сейчас я делаю что-то подобное:

```
(XSector - 1) * 1920 + X
(YSector - 1) * 1920 + Y
```

и вычисляет евклидово расстояние.

Подскажите, может существует более элегантный метод ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кроме 1920 в коде и на рисунке нет ничего общего, поэтому непонятно, как вы вычисляете сейчас. Но вообще, если известны координаты двух точек, то расстояние между ними считается по теореме Пифагора.

Comment: Я видимо плохо объяснил. У меня есть координаты самого сектора и координаты точки внутри сектора.  Нужно получить расстояние до точки  в другом секторе

Comment: А чем вам этот метод плох? По любому для вычисления расстояния точки нужно привести к одной системе координат, и описанный вами способ - самый простой и логичный.

Comment: Вычитание единицы уберите, т.к. для разности координат это не нужно, а всё остальное  - нормально.

Comment: А кстати - как будет использоваться полученное расстояние?

Comment: Это перемещение персонажа в онлайн игре